# Are there any problems using SysAllocString with literals?

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following code

```
  void Test()
  {
    BSTR aBstr = ::SysAllocString(L"blah");
    PrintBSTR(aBstr);
    ::SysFreeString(aBstr);
  }

  void PrintBSTR(BSTR _aBstr)
  {
    PrintWstring(_aBstr);
  }

  void PrintWstring(std::wstring _aWstring)
  {
    std::wcout << _aWstring << std::endl
  }
```

It works well for Debug, but I get memory corruptions in Release. Actually, I get a bad pointer when I'm into `PrintWstring`, and `_aWstring` contains rubbish. I'm guessing `SysAllocString` doesn't get on very well with literals. Any idea?

Comment: Try debugging the code and see what these variables do contain.

Comment: Works for me. You likely do something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with passing a literal to `SysAllocString`.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't get to the root of the problem, but it may have to do with how I was building my app, the different linkings I was using, maybe allocating memory in a DLL and freeing it in another...